# Moving particle

Tags: probability

I'm stuck trying to solve this problem:

> A particle starts from the origin and moves on the line $1$ unit to the right or left with probability $\frac12$ each, the successive movements being independent. Let $Y_n$ denote its position after $n$ moves. Find the following probabilities:

> (a) $P(Y_n \ge 0 \, \mathrm{for} \, 1 \le n \le 4)$; $[...]$

I'm unsure how to approach the $1\le n \le 4$ condition. I would think to add the various probabilities from $n=1,2,3,4$, but that results in a number greater than $1$.

Alternatively, I thought to add together all possible and favorable cases, so as to have $\frac{1+3+4+11}{2+4+8+16}$, but unfortunately, also this is wrong.

I'm at a bit of a loss and would appreciate any solutions/pointers. For reference, the book's solution is $\frac{3}{8}$

Comment: You are expected to give four answers, one for $n=1$, another for $n=2$, a third for $n=3$ and a final answer for $n=4$

Comment: You are asked to find $P(Y_ n \geq 0)$ for $n=1, n=2, n=3, n=4$ So, four probability  values are to be computed.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I calculated the following, given that $p_n=P(Y_n\ge 0)$: $p_1 = 1/2$; $p_2 = 3/4$; $p_3 = 1/2$; $p_4 = 11/16$, and none of these answers line up with the book's.

Comment: If the problem is transcribed correctly then Henry and Dilip's comments are wrong. You are asked for the probability of the single event that the particle remains $\ge0$ for at least four moves. Just count all the 4-move trajectories that meet this condition and divide by the total number of possible 4-move trajectories ($2^4=16$).

Comment: The valid trajectories are the four that start with RR and the two that start with RLR. We have $(4+2)/16=3/8$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: Each step is actually represented by a Bernoulli variable with parameter $p = 1/2$, so that you should construct a probability tree and count the number of valid paths. You'll end up with Karl's result.